# jQuery[number] was not called

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

Ok, I have searched this question and have found numerous answers on it but none have worked for me. 
I'm getting jQuery21006460414978209883_1395689439888 was not called error. 
The AJAX call is done right, status is 200 and the php url that i'm trying to call, i have validated its JSON and it is a valid json according to jsonlint. 
I'm using jsonp since it is a crossdomain call. 
Any advise would help me debug this. 
Here is my javascript code:

```
$.ajax({
    crossDomain: true,
    cache: false,
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://example.com/backend.php",
    data: "fdaf",
    //async: false,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function(msg){
      alert("success"+ JSON.stringify(msg));
    },
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert('error function status is : '+xhr.status);
                alert('error thrown is:  '+thrownError);
    },
    jsonp: "callback",
    complete: function (requestState) {
        alert("working");
    } 
});
```

My backend.php code is here:

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$arr = array('a' => "1", 'b' => "2", 'c' => "3", 'd' => "4");
$tr =  json_encode($arr);

echo $_GET['callback'].'['.$tr.']';
?>
```

Please advise what I am doing wrong here. Many thanks!

Comment: What's the exact error you're seeing and where are you seeing it?

Comment: @MikeC I'm getting this error, it goes into the error function right away. error thrown is:  Error: jQuery210012445046612992883_1395690899125 was not called

Comment: @adeneo ok, can you please let me know what I am doing wrong here.. here's the output of backend.php [{"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3","d":"4"}]
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is this, the output of your PHP:

```
callbackfunction[[DATA]]
```

This does not call a Javascript function. You should have this output:

```
callbackfunction([DATA])
```

With this PHP:

```
echo $_GET['callback'].'('.$tr.')';
```

Because `$tr` is an Array it will return `[DATA]`

You should only need `JSONP` if you do a Cross-Domain request. Otherwise just use a GET / POST.

Comment: can you please clarify? what I should change in my code? Thanks a lot.. here's what my php code is producing: [{"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3","d":"4"}]

Comment: The `[]` in your `echo` should be `( )`

Comment: ok, I changed that.. so my php is producing ({"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3","d":"4"}) but still I'm getting the same error jquery[random number] was not called as it goes right away into the error function.

Comment: Than you callback function is not wsset

Comment: not wsset? can you please clarify? I just don't know why it is going into the error function each time, not matter what. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I just tried the same code locally and it worked on all browsers. From my local server to remote server, the call is coming out right. However, from one remote to another remote, xhr.status is 200 yet still the same error jquery[random number] was not called.  This is getting me closer, any insights would be helpful in this regards.. Thanks again!